# SFMCsdk Notification do nothing after app got killed. In onCreate method of Application class. Android

Tags: marketing-cloud, android, salesforce-sdk-android

To init an SFMCsdk we need some data for initialization. We are getting required data from our API covered with RxJava. So, when request is made, and data is received then initialization is finished succesfully, but anyway notification do nothing when its clicked after app got killed. If those values are hardcoded, then its work as intended.
Everything is inside onCreate method in Application class.
Is there a proper way of doing that?

```
apiCall
        .makeRequest().  <--- request
        .doOnSuccess { response ->
            initialize(       <---- passing into MarketingCloudConfig.builder() and then pass it into SFMCSdk.configure
                response.accessToken,
                response.applicationId,
                response.marketingCloudServerUrl,
                response.memberId
             )
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Controlled initialization is not supported.

What is the intent of the call being made, and why can't you store the data after the first time the call is made to init on startup for 2..n initializations.

Comment: As i said, all data for initialization is stored on the server, on this call we retriev needed data. But thanks for advice for stroing that data after 1st call.